# sql cancelling query without reverting everything back

Tags: sql-server

I have been running many 'insert into' statement in one go with SQL server and sometimes while loop.

```
While
begin
  insert into

end
```

Usually it takes very long to finish. Sometimes I have to cancel the query before it finish. When I do, it reverts everything it has inserted. Is there a way that I only cancel the 'insert into' it is running now and keep what has been inserted in the previous loop?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just explicitly define where to start and end your transaction, then it should only roll back the 'current' transaction if it cancels half way through:

```
While
begin
BEGIN TRANSACTION;   
  insert into
COMMIT TRANSACTION;   

end
```

Ensure that you understand the impact of this on your data's integrity before you apply it.  E.g. checking each time you start the batch where you got to last time.

Comment: Whatever you do however within the transaction though, keep in mind that you now have to check for your data integrity yourself. Otherwise if you start that batch multiple times, your data could be corrupted due to multiple inserts of the same row.

Comment: Added a warning to the answer,  obviously depends entirely on what the `insert` actually does.  It could be self-evident how far it's got, or it could be a complete mess!

Comment: Thankss a lot. I created a unique index for the destination table before inserting. So dulplicate will not happen.